# How to define Tax Rate for Shipping

Tags: magento-1.9, tax, shipping-tax

I am working on setting up my first Magento Store. While setting up tax rates I am stuck at setting Shipping Tax rate. Tax class for shipping is set to "Shipping" tax class. I do not have a clue where to define the rate of tax applicable on Shipping. I tried to learn about it in Magento CE Manual but no substantial information is found. The tax rate to be defined for shipping is fixed at 14.5% but don't how to define a rule for tax on shipping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check **Configuration** / **Sales** / **Shipping Methods** select **Table Rate** method.

Once there change the scope of configuration to your desired website (Configuration option is website based) and you will see inputs to export **Rates** per country (Export CSV button), you can modify those and import again using same interface.

Comment: Thanks! I also found the method in the Magento Official Documentation File.

Comment: Done! I missed the scope part earlier and so had difficulty defining Table Rates.

Answer (score 0):

In the **Admin menu**, select **Sales > Tax > Product Tax Class** and edit the class you choose or create a new one. Hope this helps!